# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting this error only when I submit the form in Internet Explorer 10, not 9 and I don't get the error in FireFox either.

```
request.RequestedShipment.ShipTimestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

The `txtDate` is using a datepicker that submits `5/28/2013` to the app, this problem just started happening out of nowhere and only in IE10.  Does anyone have an idea why?

I've looked around and can't seem to find any answers in regards to this occuring in IE10 only, and I'm not really a C# coder.

Comment: That's a valid C# DateTime format. Are you positive that's the format which the C# code receives?

Comment: Even though it uses datepicker i've also tried putting 05-28-2013 2013-05-28 05/28/2013 and 2013/05/28 manually, and it gives the same error.

Comment: When you're debugging this server side code, is the value of txtDate.Text different depending on which browser is being used? If so, what are the values?

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but is your IE 10 test system/user running in a different language? Say, one that would format that date as 28/5/2013, and not know what month to use for 28?

Comment: It's client side though, I've tried putting `05-28-2013` `2013-05-28` `05/28/2013` and `2013/05/28` with the same error.

Comment: The client-side culture can be passed to the server... but 2013-05-28 should have worked anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about language, but locale. Say, US uses MM/dd/yyyy, and UK and Australia uses dd/MM/yyyy.
You should check Control Panel -> Region and language, and inspect the locale. A good way to around such confusion is to use ISO date format yyyy-MM-dd.